# Error when sharing Yammer group with external users ".. Cross-geography guests are not supported"

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, office-365, external-users, yammer

I want to share a yammer group with external user but I am getting this error:

[image]

Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a known limitation with sharing Yammer communities with guests.

> **Cross-Geography guests** – Today we enable organizations to host Yammer in two data centers – Europe and North America. *With this new guest support, users will be able to add guests from their same geography.*

**Source Documentation**: [What features are not supported for Guests?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/yammer/get-started-with-yammer/azure-ad-b2b-guests-yammer#what-features-are-not-supported-for-guests)

**Related Read**: [Yammer Support for Guest Access Reaches General Availability](https://office365itpros.com/2021/04/21/yammer-support-guest-access-reaches-general-availability/)

Comment: thanks for the reply.. so how i can overcome this error?

Comment: I don't think you will be able to do much to fix this issue unless you use the M365 tenants (user accounts) from same region. Also, raise support ticket with Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/get-help-support?view=o365-worldwide#online-support